# Export existing Azure Hybrid Connection relay to ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-hybrid-connections

Is it possible to export an **Azure Hybrid Connection relay** to an ARM template? When exporting the whole resource group, the relay is not included. The relay is defined by [this ARM template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2019-08-01/sites/hybridconnectionnamespaces/relays?tabs=json).

The ARM template I use creates a corrupt relay. But if I [add the relay manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections#add-and-create-hybrid-connections-in-your-app) instead, it works. That's the reason I need to investigate an exported ARM template.

My current ARM template:

```json
{
    "apiVersion": "2019-08-01",
    "dependsOn":
    [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('webAppName'))]"
    ],
    "name": "[concat(parameters('relayName'), '/', parameters('hybridName'))]",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "properties":
    {
        "relayArmUri": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourceGroups/', parameters('relayResourceGroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.Relay/namespaces/', parameters('relayName'), '/hybridConnections/', parameters('hybridName'))]",
        "sendKeyName": "defaultSender",
        "sendKeyValue": "[listkeys(concat(variables('hybridConnectionResourceId'), '/authorizationRules/defaultSender'), '2017-04-01').primaryKey]",
        "hostname": "[parameters('hostname')]",
        "port": "[parameters('port')]",
        "serviceBusSuffix": ".servicebus.windows.net"
    },
    "type": "hybridConnectionNamespaces/relays"
}
```

Comment: I performed the same repro in my environment , when I tried exporting the template at resource group level I can see the hybrid connection & relay as well . Here is the screenshot below
https://imgur.com/SpLE7nv
could you please clarify more on this or if I misunderstood your issue?

Comment: @VenkateshDodda-MT Thanks for your reply. I re-exported at resource group level, but neither the hybrid connection or relays are there. Maybe it's related to user rights. These hybrid connections are owned by someone else and are in another resource group.

Comment: I've created a GitHub issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-relay-dotnet/issues/149